# django model pre_save update() has problems

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

### Background:

I have Tag models that have an attribute is_obsolete (default set to False)

```
class Tag(model.Model):
    ...
    is_obsolete = False
```

I have StatusInfo models that have a foreign key to Tag through "affected_tag".

```
class StatusInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    affected_tag = ForeignKey(Tag)
```

When the StatusInfo instance is created they fire off the `pre_save()` signal to change `<StatusInfo>.affected_tag.is_obsolete=True`

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=StatusInfo)
def status_change_modification(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """
        Changes tags and concepts to be obsolete or deprecated.
        if a tag is obsolete or deprecated, all of the tag's concepts are obsolete or deprecated
        
    """

    assert hasattr(instance.affected_tag, "id")

    # set up variables
    kwargs = {}
    if instance.status == "d":
        kwargs["is_deprecated"] = True
    elif instance.status == "o":
        kwargs["is_obsolete"] = True

    inner_tag_status_change(instance, **kwargs)



def inner_tag_status_change(instance, **kwargs):
    """
    update the is_updated fields for status_info
    kwargs is either:
    kwargs = {'is_obsolete': True} # or {'is_deprecated': True}
    """
    affected = Tag.objects.filter(id=instance.affected_tag.id).first()
    affected.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
    affected.save(update_fields=list(kwargs.keys()))
```

### Problem

What I can't figure out is why when this hits the bottom of the test I still have my Tag instance `self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag.is_obsolete == False`

I've tried `.update(**kwargs)` and `.save(updated_fields=list(kwargs.keys()))` inside inner_tag_status_change() but it doesn't save the changes
It looks good when stepping through it in debug mode then it reverts back for the last line of the test.  Am I working on a separate copy or is caching a thing that I should be checking?

## in tests/test_status_model.py

```
    def test_status_set_tag_info_obsolete(self):
        """ check to see if the creation of a statusInfo 
            object which runs a pre_save signal changes 
            the soon_to_be_obsolete_tag to is_obsolete=True
        """
    
        self.assertFalse(self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag.is_obsolete)
        self.main_status_info = StatusInfoFactory(
            affected_tag=self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag,
            status="o",  # obsolete
            by=self.new_replacement_tag,
        )
    
        self.assertTrue(self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag.is_obsolete)  # still False
```

Comment: use post_save instead?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't make a difference. I'd like to know why this particular suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your test and your pre-save logic, it looks like you're updating the tag in the database but Django's cache of that tag object that attached to your model isn't be updated.

So I believe the issue is that in both `status_change_modification` and `inner_tag_status_change`, you accessed `instance.affected_tag`, but you didn't update `instance.affected_tag` directly. Instead you grabbed that tag from the database with an extra query and then saved it.

I would guess that if you updated your test to this, it would work:

```py
self.assertTrue(Tag.objects.get(id=self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag).is_obsolete)
```

Or if you used `refresh_from_db` to force a refresh on `self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag` that should work too:

```py
self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag.refresh_from_db()
self.assertTrue(self.soon_to_be_obsolete_tag.is_obsolete)
```

You might also consider updating your `inner_tag_status_change` logic to update the tag directly too (I'm not certain whether this would fix the issue you're experiencing but it would remove an extra `SELECT` query that may not be needed):

```py
def inner_tag_status_change(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.affected_tag.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
    instance.affected_tag.save(update_fields=list(kwargs.keys()))
```